# Upvote a bug in Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, bug-tracking

Running into an issue with Team Foundation Server 2010 and I'm hoping someone in the community has come up with a solution I can add as a patch to the server.

We have 2-3x QA personnel on a project I'm on, and 1 of them is running TFS for bugs as you would expect... if she finds an issue and it's logged already, she moves on.  The issue is that the rest of the IT Team is thinking she isn't doing anything, and I don't want an issue with her not getting her credit where it's due.

Is there anything around that I can plug into TFS 2010 that she can upvote the issue, so that she gets the credit for at least working on the bugs as well?  Any advice would be great (may not be a Stackoverflow question, but in that case, let's get this over to Programmers or something similar where it belongs).

Answer (score 1):

You can define a **custom** field in the TFS item template (i.e. a new drop-down) that can serve as an "upvoting" mechanism.

The issue with "upvoting" a bug is that it may be confused with its Priority. Additionally, it won't necessarily solve the problem of whether she gets credit or not (she could technically just go through the bug queue and upvote every item - doesn't mean that she found the bug herself). As an alternative (although not ideal), she could simply use the "Notes" tab in the TFS item to acknowledge that she came across the same issue.